# CSS, mis margenes no estan funcionando

Tags: html, css, web

Alguien me podria explicar que estoy haciendo mal, tengo este boton al cual tengo dentro de un div, como pueden ver el borde del contenido(boton) y el borde del contenedor(div#box) se estan tocando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya agregue un margin al boton pero parece no funcionar y aun asi se toca con el borde de su contenedor

```css
    #box {
        border: 2px solid mediumseagreen;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    .contenedor {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    #exito-icon {
        width: 250px;
    }
    
    .imagen-caja {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .boton {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #1883ba;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 2px solid #0016b0;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <br><br>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div id="box">
            <h2 class="h2">Exito!</h2>
            <div class="imagen-caja">
                <img id="exito-icon" src="{% static 'images/palomita.jpg' %}" >
            </div>
            <h4>gracias por tu contribucion de {{ monto }} dolares</h4>
    
            <br>
            <a class="boton" href="{% url 'index' %}">vuelva a la pagina de donacion</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los enlaces tienen por defecto el atributo `display: inline`, que hace que sus márgenes internos y externos no afecten al contenedor padre. Puedes usar `display: inline-block` para arreglar tu vista, creo que es lo más adecuado.

Otra opción sería modificar el contenedor principal para ampliar el margen interno inferor: `padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px`, pero no le veo sentido si se puede arreglar directamente desde el elemento que ocasiona el problema.

```css
#box {
        border: 2px solid mediumseagreen;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    
    .contenedor {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    #exito-icon {
        width: 250px;
    }
    
    .imagen-caja {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .boton {
        display:inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #1883ba;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 2px solid #0016b0;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<br><br>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div id="box">
            <h2 class="h2">¡Éxito!</h2>
            <div class="imagen-caja">
                <img id="exito-icon" src="{% static 'images/palomita.jpg' %}" >
            </div>
            <h4>Gracias por tu contribución de {{ monto }} dólares</h4>
    
            <br>
            <a class="boton" href="{% url 'index' %}">Vuelva a la pagina de donación</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que establezcas dentro de tu regla CSS un margen interior para el caso de los elementos del div con la clase box, de está forma:

```
#box {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

De modo que logres que el elemento `a` se separe del borde inferior de su etiqueta padre.

Comment: gracias por responder, no funciona ya lo intente, debe haber un problema en como las cjas estan interactuando pero no logro saber cual es

Comment: si lo hice con el #, si ati te funciona creo que el error entonces debe ser algo externo al css y html, gracias por responder

Comment: A parte de cambiar el selector considera dar una medida mayor